# Android Socket Network unreachable after reconnecting to wifi network wiith c++ Server

Tags: android, c, sockets, networking, android-wifi

I'm encountering a problem. I created an app that connects to a wifi network and retrieve data from this network via sockets.

I can easily retrieve data at the first connection to this network. However, when I disable wifi manually and reinitiate the connection to the network and socket creation programmatically, it fails saying that the socket cannot connect (Network is unreachable).

Here is my main code 
[Main.java](https://ufile.io/3shdn)

The C++ server Class
[Server.cpp](https://ufile.io/jym7s)

The server running in a thread 
[myServer.cpp](https://ufile.io/zqtxr)

And the stackTrace :

```
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: Reconnect
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: Wi-Fi not enabled
com.maxence.appwifiosselet I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: Wi-Fi succesfully enabled
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: SSID of the connected network during connecting : eduroam
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: Connection to wrong network, disconnect
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: Disconnected succesfully from connection receiver
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: Connect to the osselet wifi
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: Connect to the Wi-Fi network Osselet...
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: Conf created
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: Disconnected succesfully in enableConf
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/ConnectivityManager: requestNetwork; getAppId(CallingUid) : 10167, CallingPid : 26040
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: Disconnected from reconnect
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: Disconnected from reconnect
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: SSID of the connected network during connecting : osselet
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: SSID of the connected network during connecting : osselet
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: Network connection has been established
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: SSID of the connected network : osselet
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.WifiDataAsyncTask: Creating socket on IP 10.3.141.1:1500
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.WifiDataAsyncTask: Error creating socket
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.3.141.1 (port 1500): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:827)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at com.maxence.appwifiosselet.WifiDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(WifiDataAsyncTask.java:47)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at com.maxence.appwifiosselet.WifiDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(WifiDataAsyncTask.java:25)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:    ... 12 more
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:671)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:361)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at com.maxence.appwifiosselet.WifiDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(WifiDataAsyncTask.java:56)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at com.maxence.appwifiosselet.WifiDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(WifiDataAsyncTask.java:25)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.WifiDataAsyncTask: Error read InputStream
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.WifiDataAsyncTask: Socket closed because InputStream stopped
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.MainFragment: CloseSocketReceiver
com.maxence.appwifiosselet D/com.maxence.appwifiosselet.WifiDataAsyncTask: Start the server first
```

**EDIT :** I managed to handle a C++ client closing socket. It works fine with the client [client.cpp](https://uploadfiles.io/3h7o5) However, when I close the Android socket, the c++ server does not detect it ... Please help, it's really annoying :)

**EDIT2 :** I managed to make it work ! For some reason, when the BroadcastReceiver on the NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED is triggered and CONNECTED is returned, the network seems unreachable for few ms. I added a Thread.sleep(200) before launching the activity.

```
 class WifiConnectedStateChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                NetworkInfo.State state = networkInfo.getState();

                if (state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    changeUIToConnected();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // Start retrieving data from server
                    startWifiDataAsyncTask();

                } else if (state == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
                    if (!tryReconnect) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Network disconnected");
                        changeUIToDisconnected();
                        // Stop AsyncTask
                        stopWifiDataAsyncTask();

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected from reconnect");
                    }
                }
                // Check if connection to the right network (osselet) during connection
                else if (state == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTING) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Disconnecting to " + networkInfo.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Stacktrace? Your `stopWifiDataAsyncTask()` does not look right.

Comment: @JimmyB Here is the stacktrace

Comment: What about other apps. A browser for example. Can it still grab pages after reconnection?

Comment: `Toast.makeText(context, "Start the server first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` Why do you have to start the server again? That server should just stay in the air waiting for a new client when the old one closes.

Comment: @greenapps It's in case the Android app starts when the server is not running but I don't think it is the problem.

Comment: Why should the server not be running? You do that in onPostExecute() and your client just had connection with that server in doInBackground(). You talk nonsense.

Comment: It's only if the socket could not be created. But I assume that it is not always when the server is not running. It can be another problem, just like now. But I admit that the onPostExecute is meaningless

Comment: @greenapps The code simply assumes that, if the connection to the server fails, the server is not running. Hence the irritating messages.

Comment: You better answer my question about the browser.

Comment: @JimmyB I don't think that the server handle a client disconnection. May be it is that but it is wierd because the error message is "Network unreachable" and not something about the socket.